# Ubuntu not booting properly at all

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, nvidia

Today i tried booting my Ubuntu, but it seems like its not able to finish the boot process properly. In GRUB, when i select my kernel version it starts booting as usual but after a few seconds it shows something like these:

```
[OK] Finished libvirt-guests.service
```

or

```
[OK] Started gdm.service
```

Adding `nouveai.modeset=0` or `nouveau.nomodeset` to my kernel parameters didn't work, same outcome. If I try to access recovery mode, there's not much I can do there. `clean` doesn't find any packages to remove, `dpkg` drops a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DistUpgrade'` (something from python) and `fsck` just drops

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
/dev/sda2 is mounted
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting
```

If I try to resume the boot from there, there's just a black screen and a blinking dash.

The boot device is still the right one.

Any ideas?

Comment: `e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting` probably means the drive is gone. Other (fixable) causes are possible but much less likely. And why exactly are you trying to add Nvidia/nouveau related parameters (one of them a typo; both are wrong)? Partition/filesystems problems have nothing to do with graphics?!?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like sda2's filesystem has some serious problems... Is that your home partition, or root probably?

Try a live iso (usb, etc) and fsck from there, maybe it will let you get some more info.

And watch `dmesg` & especially /var/log/syslog (if your live iso has syslog/rsyslog/rsyslogd running, if not start it up) for messages like "read error on sda2" or other bad things.